# Is there a way where I can filter/get in between dates when in MYSQL IN Clause that handles multiple columns?

Tags: mysql

So recently I have discovered that using the `In` Clause In `MYSQL 5.7`, allows me to extract specific data base on multiple columns.

```
SELECT * FROM `Schema`.`Table` where (`ID`,`Code`) IN ((1,'AE'),(2,'AD'));
```

| ID | Code | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AE | 2021-01-01 |
| 1 | AE | 2021-01-02 |
| 1 | AE | 2021-01-03 |
| 1 | AE | 2021-01-04 |
| 2 | AD | 2021-01-01 |
| 2 | AD | 2021-01-02 |
| 2 | AD | 2021-01-03 |
| 2 | AD | 2021-01-04 |

This is amazing, But if I want to include an additional column for a particular range of Dates, it does not work. Here is the following query I have attempted.

```
SELECT * FROM `Schema`.`Table` WHERE (`ID`,`Code`,`Date`) 
IN ((1,'AE', BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-03'),(2,'AD',BETWEEN '2021-01-02' AND '2021-01-04'));
```

I could use Union ALL to merge the unique Data on the `ID` and `Code` and have the separate Date Range. But I am just wondering if my approach for the syntax is wrong, or even if there is a better way to approach this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could express this using a hybrid approach as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `Schema`.`Table`
WHERE (ID, Code) IN ((1, 'AE')) AND Date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-03' OR
      (ID, Code) IN ((2, 'AD')) AND Date BETWEEN '2021-01-02' AND '2021-01-04';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can can do it using `>=` and `<=`.

```
SELECT *
FROM `Schema`.`Table`
WHERE (ID, Code) IN (1, 'AE') AND Date >= '2021-01-01' AND Date <= '2021-01-03' 
      OR
      (ID, Code) IN (2, 'AD') AND Date >= '2021-01-02' AND Date <= '2021-01-04';
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, your query works too, but I refer the syntax with Between.